# Configure culture for client side validation in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I having very hard time to configure client side validation in my APP. I would like to it be able to accept localized `pt-BR` inputs.

I tried configure the app using at startup:

```
var locale = "pt-BR";
RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions {
    SupportedCultures   = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo(locale) },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo(locale) },
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(locale)
};
```

and I set `<html lang="pt-br">` into the main HTML file.

It works for rendering currency, date time and numbers in server side, but the client validation still expecting `en-US` input.

The client side is using `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`

How can I configure the client side validation to understand localized input ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl

Comment: @Igor I read all the documentation and  it does not seems to help very much. I was not able to find the solution

Comment: You cannot "configure" the client to take locale into account, if you use standard javascript methods to convert between strings and other types. You need to call functions from `Intl` library.

Comment: I understand now @Igor I know that the `jquery.validade` lib which is used for the client side validation, can be configured to accept localized input, but I don't know how.

Comment: You need to configure the `$.validator`. You can write your own scripts to set defaults, or use a plugin such as [Globalize.js](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper class like this:

```
public class PortugueseCulture : CultureInfo
{
    private readonly Calendar cal;
    private readonly Calendar[] optionals;

    public PortugueseCulture()
        : this("pt-BR", true)
    {
    }

    public PortugueseCulture(string cultureName, bool useUserOverride) : base(cultureName, useUserOverride)
    {
        //Your Custom Currency Numbers Calendar Culture Code
    }

    public override Calendar Calendar
    {
        get { return cal; }
    }

    public override Calendar[] OptionalCalendars
    {
        get { return optionals; }
    }
}
```

Then in Global.asax.cs add this method

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var portugueseCulture = new PortugueseCulture();
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = portugueseCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = portugueseCulture;
    }
```